# How to encode POST parameter in javascript and decode it in php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have to pass parameters using ajax.Updater to a php page. The post values to be passed contain characters like +,-,&,%,#.

I am encoding the parameters using encodeURIComponent before posting and decoding it using urldecode() in the php page.

I am unable to fetch the posted data in the php page. Please suggest how this can be handled.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us, how you are sending the request?

Comment: Please show your code. `encodeURIComponent` is the right function. You probably don't have to do any decoding in PHP. This should be done automatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An alternative to url encode is base64 encode then you can just retrieve the post data using $_POST and base64_decode() the results. base64 encode/decode is very common for example if you are already using JQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/base64-encode-and-decode

Comment: I take it I was downvoted because base64 encoding can sometimes add spurious characters to the post data.

Answer (score 3):

I used encodeURIComponent(value1). i.e I encoded each value and then posted. Prior, I was encoding the entire postBody.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use the "postBody" Option from Prototype: http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/options

Using this option you don't have to encode the data. Just send the request as a POST request and fetch the data directly from the $_POST array in PHP.

Comment: I am using "postBody" Option from Prototype. The syntax is like postBody:"field1"=value1+"field2="+value2 But if I have a "+" or "&" in the value to be passed, the "+" and "&" is not fetched in the php page Eg. if field1="grade A+" then only "grade A" appears in php page